# How to make an html table deliberately exceed the width of its container?

Tags: html, css

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ayax2q4o/)

I'm trying to make a table that contains a horizontal scrollbar where the width of any individual row can be set to whatever I want. I've tried two different approaches to achieve this and they each give me problems:

If I assign a width to my table that is larger than its containing div and apply `overflow-x: scroll`, the table exceeds the width of its container. However, I have no control over the width of my cells. Setting `td{width:'x'px;}` doesn't do anything.

If instead I apply `table-layout:fixed` to the table, I can now adjust the width of individual rows but cannot exceed the width of the table container.

How do I get the best of both worlds? I need the table to exceed the width of the container in order to get the scrollbar, while also being able to set the width of different rows to any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML table and table cells work this way by design - cells will always be confined to within the width of the table. If you want to size them like you do to normal inline-block elements, you can either:

1. Use `<div class="table">` and `<div class="cell">` to markup and style tables.

OR

2. Change the display mode in CSS. `{display: block}` for tables, `{display: inline-block}` for cells. You'd probably also need to fiddle with the display modes of other elements like `<tr>`, `<th>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>`...

A little note: just in case you are using tables as a means to layout your page content, please stop and strongly reconsider changing your approach. Tables are a nasty crutch for layout, and should really ONLY be used to display actual tabular data.

Comment: I think you have a typo in your first option. However, the 2nd option worked after adding html, body {white-space: nowrap;}, so thank you for that :)

Answer (score -1):

Set the `position: absolute;` for the element that you want to exceed it's container width. But also set `position: relative;` to its parent, so you can adjust the position.